# Use of CurrentDb.OpenRecordset in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am editing something in VBA in MS access. Can someone please tell me the difference between below two statements.

```
1. Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblOPCEPLTB")
2. Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblOPCEPLTB")
```

What I am guessing is 2nd line fetches all rows from table tblOPCEPLTB and store in rs variable. So what does 1st do? After executing 1st what should it have?

Please help here

Comment: The datasets will be identical. Use a SELECT statement when you want to restrict the fields and/or apply filter criteria and/or sort order.

Comment: After executing both statements. what will be the difference between rs and rs1?

Comment: The data retrieved is the same. Operations that can be performed can be different, as pointed out in Erik's answer.

Comment: personally instead of using currentdb.openrecordset to open that table, id use CurrentDB.TableDefs("tblOPCEPLTB").OpenRecordset

Answer (score 12):

The first statement opens a table-type recordset if that table is a local Access table (because the argument passed is a table, `dbOpenTable` is the default)

The second statement opens a dynaset-type recordset (because the argument passed is a query, `dbOpenDynaset` is the default)

The main difference between dynaset-type and table-type recordsets is that table-type recordsets support indexes.

The following code will succeed and look up the entry with a primary key value of 5

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblOPCEPLTB")
rs.Index = "PrimaryKey"
rs.Seek "=", 5
```

The following will fail, since seeks are only supported on table-type recordsets:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblOPCEPLTB")
rs.Index = "PrimaryKey"
rs.Seek "=", 5
```

If you only wish to append records to a table, then specify that when opening the recordset:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblOPCEPLTB", Options:=dbAppendOnly)
```

This way, no records will get locked or loaded, since the recordset will only support appending

Comment: My table has 2 cols and to insert a row code is first selecting all rows from table and then appening a new row at the bottom like:
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblOPCEPLTB")
    With rs
        .AddNew

        rs!PROD_AD_TYP = "Account"
        rs!ARPS_ACTION = "getAccountDetails" 
        .Update
        .Close
    End With
    Set rs = Nothing

I didn't like that, slecting whole table then adding new row is not a good programming. All I wanted to know is Can I replace 2 with 1 from my original?post?

Comment: See the edit. Next time, just ask what you want to ask. As said, the only real difference is index support, and recordsets don't load an entire table, they just load records when needed

Comment: Eric, to my understanding, a snapshot recordset is static, thus always has to load the entire set of records.

Comment: Thanks@ErikvonAsmuth. Thank you append works for me. But what if I have to insert a row middle of a table.

Comment: The problem is when your table has more than 400000 rows it takes around 20-30 to append a new record.